# unable to parse json using objectMapper of jackson where json value contains \\

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I am de serializing json string to plain java object using jackson's ObjectMapper class. ObjectMapper is throwing an exception

json string I am trying to deserialize is

```
String input="{\"id\":\"30329\",\"appId\":\"3301\",\"nodeId\":1556537156187,\"data\":\"select id,obt_marks,'\\\\m' as dummy from ltc_test_1\"}";
```

value for data key contains \ which is causing the problem, is their a way  to escape this. i want this value as is in my POJO
It can work by replacing each occurrence of \ with \\ so string will look like
\"data\":\"select id,obt_marks,'\\\\m' as dummy from ltc_test_1\"

> **Question:**   How this can be achieved using java,is there any setting in objectMapper or Jackson to tackle this problem ?

Below is pojo which i will get after de-serialization

```
public class WorkflowProcessInfo {
    private Long id;
    private Long appId;
    private Long nodeId;
    private String data;
}

////Code I am using for deserialization 
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, false);

        mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
        mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
        mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY,
                true);

        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

        try{
    return mapper.readValue(inputJson, WorkflowProcessInfo.class);
}catch(Exception e){
syso(e.getMessage())}
```

I expecting `WorkflowProcessInfo` object with values as present in json meaning, data attribute of pojo should look like below

```
WorkflowProcessInfo.data="select id,obt_marks,'\\m' as dummy from ltc_test_1"
```

instead i am getting below exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character
>   escape 'm' (code 109)  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1ea9f6af;
>   line: 1, column: 84]